# Fixed width title text with links

Tags: html, css

I have several posts like this:

```
<p>Title 1 <a href="/view/1">view</a></p>
<p>Title 2 <a href="/view/2">view</a></p>
<p>Longer Title 3 <a href="/view/3">view</a></p>
```

Is is possible to CSS them so that the title text has a fixed width, e.g. 300px, and all the 'view' links appear to the right of the text, and as a column one below the other?

Comment: Can you change the html code, or does it have to be CSS only?

Comment: Do you want the view links to remain to the right of the title text?

Comment: I can change the html, but the simpler the better ... I hoped to get the view links to be to the right of the title-texts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to change the HTML

```
p {
    width: 300px;
}

p a {
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DvYq8/

Comment: @Huangism - the OP isn't clear on this. He said he wants the view links below each other, not necessarily below the title. So a tabular layout may be what he's after.

Comment: Not sure about that. I think he means that he wants all the links to be below each other in a "different column"?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for suggestions - this is the right kind of idea here http://jsfiddle.net/ultimate_real/gK78x/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/t6a9A/

Had to modify HTML a bit...

**HTML:**

```
<p><span>Title 1</span> <a href="/view/1">view</a></p>
<p><span>Title 2</span> <a href="/view/2">view</a></p>
<p><span>Longer Title 3</span> <a href="/view/3">view</a></p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
p > span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}

p > a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's CCS code if no html modifications are allowed. You need to change `a` tag display property.

```
<style type="text/css">
a { display:block; }
p { border:1px solid #FF0000; width:300px; }
</style>
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/XxvZB/1/)

But, actually it is better to rewrite your HTML structure, to make it more reliable and easy to manage by CSS.